# Razer blade stealth 2018 ubuntu 18.04 charging bug

Tags: suspend, 18.04, lock-screen, thunderbolt, charging

Running ubuntu 18.04 on a 2018 Razer Blade Stealth with thunderbolt charger.

When I plug the charger in, it either doesn't recognize that I've plugged a charger in or the screen blanks and locks/suspends the OS. Any suggestions on preventing this?